# Adding a Path to $PATH

Tags: boot

My java files are in /home/joe/Learning/Java folder, but can not run them in home directory. Works fine when I change to the specific directory.  How can I add this to my $PATH.  I tried so many. but no avail. Can someone help

Comment: Did you right click the file choose properties and make it executabe

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run files locally without adding the path to your command, an easy way is to store them in `~/bin`.

Make sure they are executable.

Another way is to create a link in `~/bin` to the file (`ln -sf`)

I think this is the most appropriate way for a "learning" file as you mention it.

Comment: This is good advice you can move you files from terminal like this sudo cp -R /home/joe/Learning/Java/FILENAMEHERE ~/bin

Comment: The sudo will not be needed to copy them locally, and the file needs to be on the first level.